# How to have a even thickness around the mesh

Tags: modifiers

Why the mesh not have even thickness all over the mesh with solidify modifier. At the bottom the rectangular shape its not having even thickness. I tried all the options in the solidify modifier (simple, complex) etc. All the face are all oriented in same direction. May i know whats going wrong with the mesh. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to split corner edge. You can use **Edge Split** modifier if you don't care about overlapping geometry.

[image]

Or try to set *Even* and *Offset minus 1* instead, so it looks a bit nicer from some angle. But the corner will always fail.

---

**Solidify** generates a copy of each vertex with offset in face normal direction. In your case the problem is RIM. Generated faces on sides are pointed in oposite direction. Blender tries calculate average connection that results in a twist.

By other words - the result you expect require additional geometry, it is more than  - copy vertex and offset. It meams you'r asking modifier to do more than was designed.

Comment: yes that i dont want to split the corner. why the mesh dont have even thickness. Look at the center where i have mark in question. Thats the region its not having even thickness

Comment: Answer edited with more details to explain what  happened to your mesh.